# Use Array.prototype.map() and Array.prototype.filter() only to achieve the following results

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

I have this object:

```
const data = [
  { "key": "Arnav", "value": "J Access" },
  { "key": "Amit", "value": "UP Access" },
  { "key": "Amit", "value": "UP Access" },
  { "key": "Amit", "value": "UP Access01" },
  { "key": "Amit", "value": "UP Access02" },
  { "key": "Arnav", "value": "J Access01" },
  { "key": "John", "value": "EUP Access" },
  { "key": "John", "value": "EUP Access1" },    
  { "key": "Arnav", "value": "J Access02" }
];
```

I want to only use map and filter to convert it into this object:

```
const result = [
  { "key": "Arnav", "value":["J Access","J Access02", "J Access01"]},
  { "key": "Amit", "value": ["UP Access","UP Access01","UP Access02"]},
  { "key": "John", "value": ["EUP Access", "EUP Access1"]}
];
```

i.e. unique key and value pairs (array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should use `Array.prototype.reduce` to group the items, by first finding if the item is already present or not using `Array.prototype.findIndex` then processing the duplicate items using `Set`.

If it exists simply add the `value` to the existing grouped array (before checking for duplicates) , else add a new entry in the grouped/accumulated array:

```js
const data = [
  { "key": "Arnav", "value": "J Access" },
  { "key": "Amit", "value": "UP Access" },
  { "key": "Amit", "value": "UP Access" },
  { "key": "Amit", "value": "UP Access01" },
  { "key": "Amit", "value": "UP Access02" },
  { "key": "Arnav", "value": "J Access01" },
  { "key": "John", "value": "EUP Access" },
  { "key": "John", "value": "EUP Access1" },    
  { "key": "Arnav", "value": "J Access02" }
];

const grouped = data.reduce((acc, ele) => {
  const idx = acc.findIndex(obj => obj.key === ele.key);
  if(idx >= 0){
    acc[idx].value = [...new Set(acc[idx].value).add(ele.value)];
  }else{
    acc.push({key: ele.key, value: [ele.value]});
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get list of unique items. Then you can build a new object based on those items by using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and map like this:

```js
const data = [
  { "key": "Arnav", "value": "J Access" },
  { "key": "Amit", "value": "UP Access" },
  { "key": "Amit", "value": "UP Access" },
  { "key": "Amit", "value": "UP Access01" },
  { "key": "Amit", "value": "UP Access02" },
  { "key": "Arnav", "value": "J Access01" },
  { "key": "John", "value": "EUP Access" },
  { "key": "John", "value": "EUP Access1" },    
  { "key": "Arnav", "value": "J Access02" }
];

let result = [...new Set(data.map(i => i.key))]
  .map(key => ({ key, value: [...data.filter(i => i.key == key).map(i => i.value)] }))

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add some logic and a closure over the groups and filter then by the first found item of the same group.

```js
const
    data = [{ "key": "Arnav", value: "J Access" }, { key: "Amit", value: "UP Access" }, { key: "Amit", value: "UP Access" }, { key: "Amit", value: "UP Access01" }, { key: "Amit", value: "UP Access02" }, { key: "Arnav", value: "J Access01" }, { key: "John", value: "EUP Access" }, { key: "John", value: "EUP Access1" }, { key: "Arnav", value: "J Access02" }],
    result = data
        .map((hash => ({ key, value }) => ((hash[key] = (hash[key] || [])).push(value), { key, value: hash[key] }))({}))
        .filter((s => ({ key }) => !s.has(key) && s.add(key))(new Set))

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```